# Upgraded to angular 9.1 - error is Property 'supportsDOMEvents'

Tags: angular9

**Here is the issue**
error TS2416: Property 'supportsDOMEvents' in type 'ɵangular_packages_platform_browser_p
latform_browser_o' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ɵDomAdapter'.

Comment: You'll really want to add some details to this.  What is the code you're trying to run, what is the input that's raising this error, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As [@DrTeeth already mentioned](http://#comment121496088_68736155), it's hard to help w/o any further infos.

But I've had a similar problem and want to share what had helped for me: This was a *simple* inconsistency of my dependencies. I', using a 3rd party Angular Component Library which was incompatible with the newer (Ivy-enabled) version, after I updated Angular itself. For me, the error message had some details about the package in question and after updating it, too, everything worked fine.